# Using OpenWRT with OLSR to connect routers using HNA

Tags: networking, adhoc, openwrt, olsrd

As you may assume I need a little assistance here.

I have four [routers](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/TL-WDR3600.html) (TP-Link WDR3600) that I need to use to create an [Ad-Hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) network. Currently I am only dealing with two of the four routers for simplicity. All of the routers have [OpenWRT Chaos Calmer 15.05](https://openwrt.org/) OS installed on them and all of them are running the [OLSR routing protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimized_Link_State_Routing_Protocol). My question is super simple but the answer eludes me and I would love some direction on the matter.

How do I get these two (and eventually four) routers to talk to each other using [HNA](http://www.olsr.org/docs/report_html/node47.html#hna-functionality) (Host and Network Association) and the setup specified above?

Edit: they need to be connected to each other wirelessly too. End edit.

I have followed this specific [guide](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/mesh.olsr#how_to) to the T but as soon as it gets to "HOW TO Step 4" the guide breaks down in terms of application because the file they point to (/etc/olsrd.conf) does not exist in my setup. When continuing anyway and running "olsrd start" it spits out: [image: this error] Notice how it says "Could not find specific config file /etc/olsrd/olsrd.conf" and how that differs from earlier when it asked me to modify "/etc/olsrd.conf"

In addition, the folder "/etc/olsrd" also does not exist in case you are wondering. I'm at a loss regarding this. Does anybody have any input on the matter? I'm certain that I'm missing something simple.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create /etc/olsrd.conf using the template provided and uncomment the third line of /etc/config/olsrd. I would also recommend installing olsrd-mod-httpinfo using opkg like he recommends.

One thing I noticed is that he never specifies giving the wireless interface (wlan0 in my case) an IP address to communicate with the mesh. Since I believe that is required, I had to use LuCI to give the interface an IP. I think I have my setup working but I am trying to get my new OpenWRT node to communicate with my previous DD-WRT nodes right now. Might just have to change them all to OpenWRT since it offers more "customization" due to it's bare-bones type configuration.

Comment: Can you direct me to this "provided" template? I believe I know what you are talking about but want to double check.

Comment: It's the one on the guide that you read: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/mesh.olsr#how_to   (step #4)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run :

```
/usr/sbin/olsrd -d -f /etc/olsrd.conf
```